# Cookies , creating one with javascript and getting it back

Tags: javascript, cookies

At first i am not sure if using cookies is the right way.
What i basically need is a variable that i store from one page , and then to use it on another page.

If it can be done without cookies then its great , if not then i will just have to do it with cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For setting cookies within JavaScript have a look at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie).

Remember, that the data you store in cookies is transmitted with *every* request for that page or domain. So if you want to store larger amounts of data, maybe [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Local_Storage) is more suitable.

Comment: Ty , local is even better , i just didn't know about it.

Comment: Hmm one question pops up .. the link for the local storage is for mozila , i am using chrome , and i am thinking that i need different functions for different browsers ?

Comment: I think i used the wrong link up there https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Storage looks better and according to http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20storage is widely available.

Comment: Doesn't matter , all 3 links helped , ty again.